# HTTP 301 error when trying Spotify Web API with Poco

Tags: spotify, poco-libraries

In essence something like:

```
void searchNewAlbums()
{
    Poco::URI m_uri( "https://api.spotify.com" );
    Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession m_session( m_uri.getHost(),  m_uri.getPort() );
    std::string res = "https://api.spotify.com";
    int offset = 0;
    std::ostringstream oss << "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=tag%3Anew&offset=" << offset << ""
            "&limit=50&type=album&market=GB";

     std::cout << "Query string is " << oss.str() << std::endl;

     Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request( Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET,
            oss.str(), Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1 );

     Poco::Net::HTTPResponse response;
     m_session.sendRequest( request );
     std::istream& rs = m_session.receiveResponse( response );
     std::string rsStr(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(rs), {});
}
```

I keep getting an HTTP 301 (Moved permanently) response but if I type the URL into the Browser I get a proper response with JSON.

I have tried HTTPSClientSession but get nowhere with that. (I just get invalid state). I also tried the URL with http instead of https which works in the browser but not in the program.

I am stuck here as I have no idea how to get it to work.
(If I need to use HTTPSClientSession please advise how I don't get invalid state errors).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I stumbled upon an answer to my question in another question. I needed HTTPSSession and needed one of these:

```
const Poco::Net::Context::Ptr context( 
    new Poco::Net::Context( Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", 
     "",Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_NONE ) );
```